# Why is "if [[ ... ]] then" (with no semicolon or newline) valid in ksh but not bash?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I noticed a difference between KSH and Bash, and I'm looking for where this is documented, or perhaps a confirmation that one or the other is a bug.

In Korn Shell (seen on KSH88 and KSH93), this command works fine, and the result "yes" is printed:

```
if [[ -z "" ]] then echo yes ; fi       # Note no ';' after the ']]'
```

In Bash, I get a `syntax error near unexpected token 'then'`.

This behavior is only if I use the double brackets.  If I use the single-bracketed form of conditional expression, both KSH and Bash give me a syntax error without the semicolon, but complain about the `fi` instead of the `then`.

Is this a bug or a feature? In ksh or Bash?  I note that the man pages for Bash and ksh have a slightly different syntax for `if`, but that difference doesn't seem to apply to this case.

---

**Edit:** Someone (@jp48) pointed out what would be a significant difference in the syntax definition between the `bash` and the `ksh` man pages. However, looking at the Solaris (11.3) [man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/ksh-1.html), which matches the AST [source code](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/sh.1), the syntax is:

```
if list ;then list [ ;elif list ;then list ] ... [ ;else list ] ;fi
```

The difference between that and the Bash man page is the placement (not the presence) of the semicolons before the `elif`/`else`/`fi` rather than after the `list`:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

The alternate syntax without the semicolons comes from a public domain version of ksh (possibly PDksh), not the "official" ksh release.

Comment: @charles-duffy: I appreciate the attempt to clarify the question title, but the situation I describe is _not_ when using `test` as part of the `if`, it is only when using the `[[` - `]]` construct.

Comment: Oops -- quite right. Corrected the title (while keeping it specific to the syntax in question, vs the utterly general "parse difference").

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: not a bug, according to [ksh man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh).

---

A main the difference between `[` and `[[` is that `[` is a keyword and `[[` is a builtin in both shells. Note that the "fallback exectuable" `/bin/[` (which is essentially `/bin/test`) is never used for performance reasons, but what follows is better understood if we pretend this command were executed.

It is then noteworthy that `]]` is also a keyword but `]` is just a parameter passed to `[`/`test`.

Here is some proof (almost same output in both shells):

```
$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword
$ type ]]
]] is a shell keyword
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
$ type ]
***: not found
```

---

Having explained this let's see what happens in your example.

bash is behaving as expected according to this [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (i.e. it *requires* the `;`):

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
```

Let's then focus on ksh, for reference I'll use FreeBSD's [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ksh).

The syntax of `if` in ksh is as follows

```
if list then list [elif list then list] ... [else list] fi
```

And a list in ksh:

> must end with a semicolon, a newline or a (syntactically correct)
>   reserved word

And so `[...]` without `;` is not a valid *list* (remember that the last `]` is NOT a keyword nor builtin, but a "parameter" passed to `[`).

Whereas `[[...]]` is a valid *list* because `]]` is a *syntactically correct reserved word*.

In conclusion, it is not a bug as it obeys the spec; of course it is not best practice not to use the `;` (or newline) and probably not POSIX compliant.

Comment: 6-sentences and its `TL;DR:` for you? Good answer, but I don't get the reference to not reading.

Comment: "TL;DR" was ony the first line :). I tend to edit a lot after sending, my fault...

Comment: That makes sense, I was left scratching my head. Great effort on the answer, correct, upvoted, but TL;DR: wtf? `:)`

Comment: Ah well, the "TL;DR" part is supposed to be a quick summary directed at the people that won't care reading the whole thing, not for myself, lol. Source: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl%3Bdr

Comment: I was looking at the Solaris man page (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/ksh-1.html), where the syntax for `if` includes the semicolons. This is also true for the source code for the ksh man page in the ksh source tree (https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/ksh93/ksh.1).
The man page you are quoting from seems to be from PDksh, or whatever was distributed with OpenBSD.

Comment: Interesting. Then I guess in that case it's a bug in the documentation or in the implementation as they don't agree with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they're not *actually* the same shell so you can't call it a bug if they react differently :-)

For `bash`, it's plainly spelt out in the `man` page, there's most definitely a semicolon before the `then`:

> `if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi`

There's also a similar line in my `ksh` `man` page so, if I was *forced* to pick out one for misbehaving, it would be `ksh`. But I haven't done a deep dive into it to see if there's some other option which may affect this. A cursory glance just states (for both) that newlines may substitute for the semicolon.

But, bottom line, if you follow the syntax as described, you shouldn't have any issues.